# java run method in custom class

Tags: java

So I am making an application with custom menus. I have two types of classes for this, the MenuContainer class, and MenuOption class. The MenuContainer decides the size, location and align of the menu, and the MenuOption decides string to be show, font, color and so on. I also wanted to add a piece of code to each MenuOption, the code decides what is to happen when the MenuOption is clicked. So each MenuOption has its own unique code that is set when creating a new MenuOption. How do I do this? I am hoping something like this may work:

```
MenuOption option1 = new MenuOption("Option1",font,color) {

    public void run() {

        //code to be executed

    }

};

option1.run();  //running the code
```

I don't know if this is asked often, but I searched and found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach looks fine, so far (despite the fact, that there are already GUI frameworks handling menumechanisms).

Keep in mind, that you created an anonymous subclass of `MenuOption`, where you put your `run` method. But the variable `option1` is of type MenuOption (not the anonymous subtype). For being able to call the method `run()` it must be declared in the class `MenuOption`.

Like so:

```
public class MenuOption {
    ...
    public void run() { /* default implementation does nothing */ }
    ...
}
```

Now, your anonymous subclass overrides the `run` method, which nevertheless can be called via expressions that evaluate to type `MenuOption`.

Whether a user clicked the menu option or not, is a whole other thing. But if you are able to detect such a click, just call the `run` method on the clicked option.

Comment: Ah, this was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. I can apply this many other places than the menu. :)

Comment: Hmmm ... This is called subtype polymorphism, and is a key concept in object-oriented programming. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Thread Method instead:

```
 public void Hello(){
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
               System.out.print("HELLO"); 
               try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Class2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            }


        }
    }.start();
}
```